# Полнота условий

Tags: комбинаторика, дискретная-математика, логические-выражения

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть задача, которую не понимаю как можно красиво алгоритмически решить.

Условие: Пользователь может задавать набор правил(условия для предикатов), для примера, рассмотрим правила применений комиссий для платежа:

- платежная система{Visa, Mastercard, ChinaUnionPay, null}
- Операция за рубежом{да, нет, null}
- Страна{RU,EN,....,null}
- .....

Значение null означает что свойство в предикате не проверяется. Из наборов свойств строится конъюнкции

Пользователь задает ряд правил

- для Visa за рубежом в Индии комиссия 5%
- для Mastercard комиссия 3%
- для России комиссия 1%
- ....
- остальное(null, null, nulll)

Задача: есть ли в наборе правил пропуски или они покрывают все возможные варианты, уверен что есть какойнибудь хороший алгоритм для этих целей, просьба дать наводку на него

Comment: "покрывают все возможные варианты" варианты чего покрывают?

Comment: условно что в правилах нет "дырок", что не получится так, что для платежа не будет выбрана ни одна комиссия. По сути если есть условие остальное(null, null, nulll) то по умолчанию дырок нет. Но если настроили комиссии скажем для Visa/Mastercard а про CUP забыли, то выходит у нас есть дырка. Решением в лоб кажется взять все возможные комбинации полей и прогнать их через предикаты, но может есть что-то посимпотичней

Comment: Создайте таблицу. Столбцы Платёжная система, строки Операции. Ячейки размер скидки. Тогда условие полноты: в каждом столбце хотя бы одно число

Comment: Не понял совета.Правила комиссий может задать пользователь он может ошибиться, к примеру 1 правило) Visa Россия - 2%; 2 правило) Mastercard 3% 3) Правило CUP 1% получается что все возможные ПС мы перечислили но 1 правило только для России и если будет VISA Украина, то мы не сможем её тарифицировать - есть дырка

Comment: Тут вопрос более абстрактный: есть n свойств каждое из которых может принимать m_n значений, из набора таких свойств можно строить конъюнкции, как понять что список конъюнкций полон, то есть при проверке любого объекта из заданных свойств будет выбрана хотябы одна из них

Comment: Пусть есть n-мерный вектор. Первые n-1 координаты это свойства, n-я это результат (скидка) Координаты свойств это 0 (любое) или натуральное число (порядковый номер свойства). Пусть есть k таких векторов. Пользователь задает свой вектор. Задача: есть ли он в множестве заданных k векторов. Правильно? Или шире: можно ли построить вектор, которого заведомо не будет в наборе? Опишите пожалуйста формат запроса.